# How to access cookie and check if it has expired using okhttp3 and PersistentCookieStore?

Tags: android, cookies, okhttp

I am working on an Android app in which a log in post request is made to a webservice. The request returns a cookie which expires in 20 minutes.

Using okhttp3 and this [PersistentCookieStore](https://github.com/franmontiel/PersistentCookieJar) library, I got the cookie to be stored and subsequently added it as request header to access authentication-required get requests (e.g. personal information that are non-public).

The code goes this way,

```
CookieJar myCookieJar = new PersistentCookieJar(new SetCookieCache(), 
new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(this));

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().cookieJar(HttpRequests.cookieJar).build();
```

I then call a method like this inside an (after I have gone through another log in Async task to get the cookie) Async task to perform a get request that requires authentication,

```
public static String PostReq(String url, String json) {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .addHeader("Cookie", "key=value")
            .post(body)
            .build();
    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
        return response.body().string();
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

The .addHeader("Cookie", "key=value") adds the cookie to the header to tell the webservice that I am authenticated.

Here comes my difficulty. Since the cookie expires after 20 minutes, I would like to be able to access the cookie itself to check for the expiration time and possibly redirect the user to the log in activity by calling the method,

```
myCookie.expiresAt()
```

and comparing it to

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

I tried to look at the PersistentCookieStore codes and found that it uses a SharedPreference with the key "CookiePersistence". I looked inside this file while my emulator was running the app and found it to be empty however.

How would I be able to access this cookie that I have obtained? Much thanks for any advice to be given.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is old, but I was facing the same problem, and here is how I fixed it.

Hold a reference to your `SetCookieCache` used to instantiate your `CookieJar`:

```
SetCookieCache cookieCache = new SetCookieCache();
CookieJar myCookieJar = new PersistentCookieJar(
   cookieCache, 
   new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(this)
);
```

Then use this to find your cookie and check it:

```
  for (Cookie cookie : cookieCache) {
     if (cookie.name().equals("cookie_name") && cookie.persistent()) {
        //cookie is still good
        break;
     }
  }
```

Or use `cookie.expiresAt()` to do your thing.